# HttpServlet Request in method remoted by DWR

Tags: java, servlets, dwr

I have a Following JSP:

```
            <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" id =upfile"size="50" /> <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="javascript:uploadPartnerDetails();" class="buttons">
            </form>
```

And DWR Script which calls remoted Java Method:

```
  function uploadPartnerDetails() {
  SMUDWR.uploadPartnerDetails(function(data) {
    dwr.util.setValue("UserTypeDiv", data, {
        escapeHtml: false
    });

});
}
```

The Remoted Method uploadPartnerDetails()is:

```
try {
        WebContext wctx = WebContextFactory.get();
       HttpServletRequest request = wctx.getHttpServletRequest();

        // checks if the request actually contains upload file
        if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            // if not, we stop here

        }
```

I get This Error :

the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/form-data stream, content type header is text/plain

The Problem is the request above does not contain multipart/form-data.
How to I get that from this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general DWR calls are AJAX calls and in AJAX we cannot upload files just like form data.
There are different ways to upload files using AJAX calls

Find different ways provided in answers to this question [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Go through these and you will get better understanding of file handling with AJAX

Comment: We are using DWR script to set JSP's, therefore the the request should go through the DWR so that the resultant JSP could be set via the same script. For e.g my above dwr scripts calls the java function which would write the files and return the JSP which would then be set inside 'UserTypeDiv' using the same DWR script